# Lambda Does not support Base64 too large - C#

Tags: c#, .net, aws-lambda, base64

I'm creating a function in a lambda with .Net 6.0 that needs to receive a base64 string (Image).

However, I can only get it to receive this base64 String if the image is small (Example: 100 x 100), when the image is much larger than that, Lambda doesn't understand the JSON and returns null.

I'm using the AWS test tool to perform the tests, how can I get a larger BASE64 String?

```
public bool FunctionHandler(DadosApData dadosApData, ILambdaContext context)
{
    
    LambdaLogger.Log("Inicio dos testes");

    var teste = _enviarMicrosoftFunction.TestarEnvio(dadosApData);

    return true;
}
```

This is my model:

```
    public class DadosApData
{
    public string Base64Foto { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string ReColaborador { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a hard limit on payload size of 6MB. Would this explain your problem?

Comment: @Corey Wouldn't explain since my json is 442kb